# Issues with Interactive Waypoint Follower in ROS2 Galactic Navigation2 GPS Waypoint Follower Tutorial

Tags: gps, nav2, ros-galactic, nav2d-tutorials, qos

I'm working through the [ROS2 Galactic Navigation2 GPS Waypoint Follower tutorial](https://navigation.ros.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_with_gps.html)  and have encountered a couple of issues that I'm struggling to resolve.

1. **QoS Incompatibility:** The GPS plugin (**my_gps_plugin**) publishes on /gps/fix with **BEST_EFFORT** reliability. However, the
   mapviz node subscribes with **RELIABLE** QoS, leading to
   incompatibility. I successfully modified the navsat_transform node
   to subscribe in BEST_EFFORT mode, but I couldn't find a way to
   adjust this for the mapviz node. I also modified the subscription of
   /gps/fix to BEST_EFFORT inside the initialize_origin.py script from
   the swri_transform_util package. Is there a way to **configure QoS for
   mapviz?**
2. **Teleop Twist Keyboard Issue:** The teleop_twist_keyboard node did not
   work as expected for ROS2 Galactic. However, using the command line
   to publish velocity commands to /cmd_vel successfully moved the
   robot in Gazebo, Mapviz, and Rviz. [Teleop_Keyboard not Working for Galactic Video](https://youtu.be/avryMjTW7vI)
3. **Interactive Waypoint Follower Script Modification**:I encountered a TypeError in the interactive_waypoint_follower.py script, which
   **was resolved by removing the "basic_navigator" argument from the BasicNavigator class instantiation**. However, the script
   functionality to send a destination to the robot using an arrow in
   Mapviz is not working. After left-clicking on a spot in Mapviz and
   then clicking over it, **the script keeps waiting for the
   robot_localization/get_state service, which seems to be
   unavailable:**

   [INFO] [1705291020.254290610] [basic_navigator]: robot_localization/get_state service not available, waiting...

[Get State Service Issue Video](https://youtu.be/CGDxHV9OaEg)

**Additional Information:**

- **I've installed SWRI packages from source** (ros2-devel branch) and compiled them to adjust the QoS settings.
- Using binary installations leads to issues with the map-to-robot's base transform, possibly due to the **/gps/fix QoS topic incompatibility.**
- I also encountered an **order-of-execution issue with the launch files, which I temporarily resolved by launching mapviz**.launch.py first, followed by the other launch files.[Reorder Launch Files "Partial Solution Video"](https://youtu.be/LnbBqDpVobw) This workaround was based on a suggestion in this [Github Issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/issues/73).

I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve these issues, **particularly the unavailability of the robot_localization/get_state service and the functionality of the interactive_waypoint_follower.py script.**

Is the tutorial fully compatible with ROS2 Galactic?

Comment: I have answered here: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/107630/interactive-waypoint-follower-script-in-navigation2-gps-waypoint-follower-tutori/107714#107714